# I need help converting my code from c++ to java

Tags: java, c++

One of my assignments is to convert a famous coding game called NIM from C++ to Java using three different methods. I'm having trouble converting it from C++ to Java. Can anyone help me fix my problem?

This is what they gave me in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream.h>
#include <lvp\random.h>
#include <lvp\bool.h>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void UserMove(int &NumStones)
/* Pre: NumStones > 0
 Post: User has taken 1, 2, or 3 stones from pile */
{
    cout << "How many would you like? ";
    int TakeStones;
    cin >> TakeStones;
    while (TakeStones<1 || TakeStones>3 || TakeStones>NumStones) {
        cout << "Value must be between 1 and 3" << endl;
        cout << "How many would you like? ";
        cin >> TakeStones;
    }
    NumStones-=TakeStones;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ComputerMove(int &NumStones)
/* Pre: NumStones > 0
 Post: Computer has taken 1, 2, or 3 stones from pile */
{
    int TakeStones;
    do {
        TakeStones=1+random(3);
    } while (TakeStones<1 || TakeStones>3 || TakeStones>NumStones);
    cout << "The computer takes " << TakeStones << "." << endl;
    NumStones-=TakeStones;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void PlayNim(NumStones)
/* Post: A game of Nim played with NumStones stones */
{
    while (true) {
        if (NumStones>0) {
            cout << "There are " << NumStones << " stones. ";
            UserMove(NumStones);
        }
        else {
            cout << "You win!";
            break; 
        }
        if (NumStones>0) {
            cout << "There are " << NumStones << " stones. ";
            ComputerMove(NumStones);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Computer wins!";
            break;
        }
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    randomize();
    int NumStones=15+random(16);
    PlayNim(NumStones);
    return(0);
}
```

And this is what I got from converting it over to Java:

```java
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Nim {

    public static void Usermove(int numstones) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        numstones = 0;
        int takestones;
        System.out.println("How many would you like: ");
        takestones = input.nextInt();
        while (takestones > numstones) {
            System.out.println("Value must be between 1 and 3");
            System.out.println("How many would you like? ");
            takestones = input.nextInt();
        }
        numstones-=takestones;
    }
    public static void Computermove(int numstones) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int takestones;
        int random = rand.nextInt(3);
        do {
            takestones=1 + random;
        } while (takestones > numstones);
        System.out.println("The computer takes" + takestones + ".");
        numstones-=takestones;
    }
    public static void PlayNim(int numstones) {
        while(true){
            if (numstones>0) {
                System.out.println("There are" + numstones + "stones");
                Usermove(numstones);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("You Win!");
                break;
            }
            if (numstones>0) {
                System.out.println("There are" + numstones + "stones");
                Computermove(numstones);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = rand.nextInt(16);
        int NumStones=15+random;
        PlayNim(NumStones);

        return(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble" is not a useful problem statement.  What trouble are you having?  What help do you need?  Is your program failing to work in some way?  If so, how? Please [edit] your question to include any error(s) or incorrect behavior you're getting, and ask a specific question about whatever problem you're having.

Comment: Source code in any language describes the behaviour of a program. What you want to ask is not "How do I translate this code?" it is "How do I implement the described behaviour?" This makes the C++ code irrelevant. Assuming you understand the behaviour of described by the C++ code, that is. If you don't then your question should be to firm up your understanding of the C++ code's behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I see several issues with your Java code.

`UserMove()` in the Java code sets `numstones=0` upon entry, whereas `UserMove()` in the C++ code does not do that.  You don't want `UserMove()` to zero out the input before modifying it.

The `while` loop of `UserMove()` in the Java code does not match the `while` loop of `UserMove()` in the C++ code.  You are not checking the user's input to make sure it is between 1..3, inclusive.

The `do..while` loop of `ComputerMove()` in the Java code does not match the `do..while` loop of `ComputerMove()` in the C++ code.  The C++ code generates a new random number on each loop iteration, but the Java code generates one random number before the loop and then reuses it on each iteration.

But, most importantly, in the C++ code, `UserMove()` and `ComputerMove()` (and presumably `PlayNim()`, too) take their `int` parameters **by reference**, which allows any modifications made by the functions to their parameter values to be reflected back to variables in the callers.  However, in the Java code, the same functions take their `int` parameters **by value** instead, and as such any modifications made to their parameter values are not reflected back to the callers.

Java does not support pass-by-reference semantics, so you will have to re-write the logic a little bit.  There are several ways you can do that.

You can wrap the `int` inside of a mutable class wrapper, such as Java's [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) or Apache's [`MutableInt`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableInt.html), and pass around an instance of that class, eg:

```java
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable;

public class Nim {

    public static void Usermove(MutableInt numstones) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int takestones;
        System.out.println("How many would you like: ");
        takestones = input.nextInt();
        while ((TakeStones < 1) || (TakeStones > 3) || (TakeStones > NumStones)) {
            System.out.println("Value must be between 1 and 3");
            System.out.println("How many would you like? ");
            takestones = input.nextInt();
        }
        numstones.subtract(takestones);
    }

    public static void Computermove(MutableInt numstones) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int takestones;
        do {
            takestones = 1 + rand.nextInt(3);
        }
        while ((TakeStones < 1) || (TakeStones > 3) || (TakeStones > NumStones));
        System.out.println("The computer takes " + Integer.toString(takestones) + ".");
        numstones.subtract(takestones);
    }

    public static void PlayNim(MutableInt numstones) {
        while (true) {
            if (numstones.intValue() > 0) {
                System.out.println("There are " + numstones.toString() + " stones");
                Usermove(numstones);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("You Win!");
                break;
            }
            if (numstones.intValue() > 0) {
                System.out.println("There are " + numstones.toString() + " stones");
                Computermove(numstones);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        MutableInt NumStones = new MutableInt(15 + rand.nextInt(16));
        PlayNim(NumStones);
    }
}
```

You can use return values instead of pass-by-reference parameters, eg:

```java
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Nim {

    public static int Usermove(int numstones) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int takestones;
        System.out.println("How many would you like: ");
        takestones = input.nextInt();
        while ((TakeStones < 1) || (TakeStones > 3) || (TakeStones > NumStones)) {
            System.out.println("Value must be between 1 and 3");
            System.out.println("How many would you like? ");
            takestones = input.nextInt();
        }
        return numstones - takestones;
    }

    public static int Computermove(int numstones) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int takestones;
        do {
            takestones = 1 + rand.nextInt(3);
        }
        while ((TakeStones < 1) || (TakeStones > 3) || (TakeStones > NumStones));
        System.out.println("The computer takes " + takestones + ".");
        return numstones - takestones;
    }

    public static int PlayNim(int numstones) {
        while (true) {
            if (numstones > 0) {
                System.out.println("There are " + Integer.toString(numstones) + " stones");
                numstones = Usermove(numstones);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("You Win!");
                break;
            }
            if (numstones > 0) {
                System.out.println("There are " + Integer.toString(numstones) + " stones");
                numstones = Computermove(numstones);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int NumStones = 15 + rand.nextInt(16);
        PlayNim(NumStones);
    }
}
```

You can move the `int` into the `Nim` class itself, and remove the `static` from the class methods, eg:

```java
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Nim {

    int numstones;
    Random rand;

    public Nim() {
        rand = new Random();
        numstones = 15 + rand.nextInt(16);
    }

    public void Usermove() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int takestones;
        System.out.println("How many would you like: ");
        takestones = input.nextInt();
        while ((TakeStones < 1) || (TakeStones > 3) || (TakeStones > NumStones)) {
            System.out.println("Value must be between 1 and 3");
            System.out.println("How many would you like? ");
            takestones = input.nextInt();
        }
        numstones -= takestones;
    }

    public void Computermove() {
        int takestones;
        do {
            takestones = 1 + rand.nextInt(3);
        }
        while ((TakeStones < 1) || (TakeStones > 3) || (TakeStones > NumStones));
        System.out.println("The computer takes " + Integer.toString(takestones) + ".");
        numstones -= takestones;
    }

    public void PlayNim() {
        while (true) {
            if (numstones > 0) {
                System.out.println("There are " + Integer.toString(numstones) + " stones");
                Usermove();
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("You Win!");
                break;
            }
            if (numstones > 0) {
                System.out.println("There are " + Integer.toString(numstones) + " stones");
                Computermove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nim game = new Nim();
        game.PlayNim();
    }
}
```